# How to stop the beginning of my function's loop from repeating

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, python-3.4

I have created a code in which the user will input their choice which will continue in a loop if the variable 'contin' equals "yes". When the user enters the choice "no" or any other input it will print their overall answers or the error message and end the loop. Instead it then repeats the beginning of the function (in this case it's whether the user wanted to continue or not). Is there a way for me to prevent this from happening? 
This is the code:

```
def userinput():

    while True:
        contin = input("Do you wish to continue the game? If so enter 'yes'. If not enter 'no'.")
        if contin == 'yes':
            print(symbol_dictionary["#"]+symbol_dictionary["+"]+symbol_dictionary["/"]+symbol_dictionary["0"]+symbol_dictionary["8"]+symbol_dictionary["4"]+symbol_dictionary["&"]+symbol_dictionary['"']

            guess = input("What symbol do you wish to change? ")

            symbol_dictionary[guess] = input("Input what letter you wish to change the symbol to.(Make sure the letter is in capitals.) ")

            print(symbol_dictionary["#"]+symbol_dictionary["+"]+symbol_dictionary["/"]+symbol_dictionary["0"]+symbol_dictionary["8"]+symbol_dictionary["4"]+symbol_dictionary["&"]+symbol_dictionary['"'])

        elif contin == ('no'):
            print ("These were your overall answers:")
            print(symbol_dictionary["#"]+symbol_dictionary["+"]+symbol_dictionary["/"]+symbol_dictionary["0"]+symbol_dictionary["8"]+symbol_dictionary["4"]+symbol_dictionary["&"]+symbol_dictionary['"'])

            if symbol_dictionary == {"#": "A","+":"C", "/":"Q", "0":"U", "8":"I",
                         "4":"R", "&":"E",'"':'D', "3":"L", "*":"M",
                         "%":"N", "2":"S", ":":"T", "1":"O",",":"J",
                         "$":"K", "!":"H", "7":"Z", "-":"Y", ".":"G",
                         "'":"W",")":"F", "6":"B", "5":"X", "9":"V"}:
                print("Well done! You have completed the game!")

        else:
            print("Please enter a valid input.")
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to replace code which has nothing in common with question using comments, `pass` or whatever; this would make your problem easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is exit the function; add a `return` in your `no` branch:

```
elif contin == ('no'):
    print ("These were your overall answers:")
    print(symbol_dictionary["#"]+symbol_dictionary["+"]+symbol_dictionary["/"]+symbol_dictionary["0"]+symbol_dictionary["8"]+symbol_dictionary["4"]+symbol_dictionary["&"]+symbol_dictionary['"'])

    if symbol_dictionary == {"#": "A","+":"C", "/":"Q", "0":"U", "8":"I",
                 "4":"R", "&":"E",'"':'D', "3":"L", "*":"M",
                 "%":"N", "2":"S", ":":"T", "1":"O",",":"J",
                 "$":"K", "!":"H", "7":"Z", "-":"Y", ".":"G",
                 "'":"W",")":"F", "6":"B", "5":"X", "9":"V"}:
        print("Well done! You have completed the game!")

    # exit the function
    return
```

Comment: this helped me a lot. I've only started my GCSE in computer science and my teacher never taught me this. Thank you :3

Answer (score 0):

Just add a break or a return at the end of the elif statement:

```
print("Well done! You have completed the game!")
break # or return
```

This will exit the loop. Break makes more sense in this context.